# Rails 5: where to put start-up check that doesn't trigger unless serving the app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I was hoping to put in some sanity checks on Rails (v5) application startup to ensure that all necessary ENV variables / configuration was properly set.

However, I want to run these checks only if I'm actually running the server. I don't want it happening any time the Rails environment is loaded, e.g., running tests, asset precompilation (including with `RAILS_ENV=production`), `rails c`, etc.

Is there a place in the Rails start-up chain that I could insert those sanity checks without affecting all Rails-related tasks?

Comment: `config/environments/production.rb` ?

Comment: Fires when precompiling assets, running tests. The issue isn't just restricting to production env (that's easy); it's avoiding the check during all the other side use cases that load the environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting challenge. The problem is that (virtually) the entire application is loaded regardless of whether you're running tests, pre-compiling assets or anything else. The only thing that's different is that you have the process residing in memory.

Have you considered creating a production validation task that you run in your deployment process prior to launching the server process?

EDIT : Additional Thoughts

Looking at the `rails server` command, it calls an instance of `Rails::Server`, a subclass of `Rack::Server` (whereas `rails console` calls an instance of `Rails::Console`).

You have two choices:

#### Task (Best Choice)

Create a rake task that you execute during your deployment process prior to starting the server process. It should raise an error if the configuration is not valid, which should halt your deployment process.

I strongly suggest this approach. It's self-contained, you can test it far easier, and you don't have to meddle with the internals of the server process.

#### Monkey Patch `Rails::Server#start`

Monkey patch `Rails::Server` (probably `Server#start`) so it runs your validation logic if it's running in a production environment. If it doesn't, throw an error. This is ugly, you won't be able to test it easily, and it violates my sense of order :P

---

I know you don't want this logic to run in production environment in non-server use cases but my production deployments are always configured completely regardless of what I do with them. I've been debating setting up a validation step myself.

Comment: Thanks for the very thoughtful answer! Perhaps you should make your official answer more clearly the "Task" option? I agree with you that it makes far more sense to approach it that way.

Comment: Also regarding "run validation in all production environments," the reason I personally can't do that is because I'm running off of containers, and I want to pre-load as much work as possible during build (e.g., asset precompilation), but I can't (and shouldn't) pass in runtime secrets during container builds. That applies to my specific use case only, however.

Comment: @honktronic done! Thanks for the feedback :) And thanks for clarifying the production server only question :)